# how to draw a curve in the bottom center of the container?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to code this screen, I came to this container and I found it hard to code, I tried Clippath but i could not find my desired shape, here is the desired shape with the bottom that i want to put in the empty space of the container , how can I acheive this shape , i have tried to use stack but it did not work because it added extra space:

[image]

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Your questions about code, i.e. debugging questions like these, are served by not only providing the error message, but also the code itself, a [mre]. We are not clairvoyant, so we cannot help you to debug code you do not show us. Also showing what you have already tried to solve the problem is appreciated. [edit] the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Stack Widget` and `CircularNotchedRectangle` together to obtain something like this.

You can examine this Bottom App Bar code and imply for your code.

```
 return BottomAppBar(
      shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
            onPressed: () {
              // Menu button onPressed action
            },
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.search),
            onPressed: () {
              // Search button onPressed action
            },
          ),
```